# How to change the color of the navigation bar from an input method service?

Tags: android, colors, keyboard, navigationbar

I am working on a custom keyboard, so I implemented a class that implements an `InputMethodService`. There are already many posts about changing the color of the navigation bar in a regular activity - this is done by calling `getWindow().setNavigationBarColor()`, but I want to do the same for my keyboard: adjust the color of the navigation bar to the background color of my keyboard!

In an `InputMethodService`, I can access a window by `getWindow()`, but it is a instance of the `SoftInputWindow` class, so it does not offer a `setNavigationBarColor` method. Does anybody know how to achieve this?

There is a beta version of Gboard that can adjust the color of the navigation bar, so it seems to be possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `getWindow().getWindow()` inside the `InputMethodService` instead of just the single `getWindow()` call.

It seems that the first `getWindow()` call returns a `SoftInputWindow` which is a type of `Dialog`, but you can call `getWindow()` again on it to get a `PhoneWindow` that is a proper `Window`, and that has the function you're looking for.

If you need a full example to look at, [here's a code sample from Google's own codebase](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ThemedNavBarKeyboard/src/com/example/android/themednavbarkeyboard/ThemedNavBarKeyboard.java). I ran into this problem recently myself and this example is how I figured out how to do it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was looking for a solution such a long time! :-)